# Let $p$, $q$ be primes such that $q \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $p = 4q+1$. Show that $100^{q} \not\equiv 1\pmod{p} $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$, $q$ be two primes such that $q \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $p = 4q+1$.

> Show that $$100^{q} \not\equiv 1\pmod{p} $$

Here is one way that I tried to tackle this (and failed, obviously...):

Assume by contradiction that $100^{q} \equiv 1\pmod{p} $. By Fermat's little Theorem it follows that: $$100^{q} \equiv 100 \pmod{q}$$ This is where I got stuck. However, I did notice that:
$$p \equiv 1\pmod{q}$$ 
$$p \equiv -1\pmod{5}$$

But these congruences didn't help me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we negate the conclusion, we have 
$$
100^q\equiv 1 (\textrm{ mod }p),$$
and this is equivalent to the existence $x$ in the following 
$$
100\equiv x^4  (\textrm{ mod }p)$$
This reduces to $
10 \equiv x^2  (\textrm{ mod }p)$, or $
-10 \equiv x^2 (\textrm{ mod }p)$

Both of them cannot be true since 
$$
\left(\frac{10}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-10}{p}\right) = -1.$$

Comment: Wow, what a great answer ! Thanks !

Comment: why $100\equiv x^4  (\textrm{ mod }p)$?

Comment: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=F6aJtNcwyw8C&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=n-th+power+residue&source=bl&ots=S1-rSfrumQ&sig=iPhuJxmMaRy07b3T625b1IovGrI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WlKoUfz6G4OE4gTlt4DoBQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=n-th%20power%20residue&f=false Theorem 4.13